# Finding element by link in PHP Selenium

Tags: php, selenium

I'm using Selenium with PHP and I was wondering if there is any way to find an element by its href. For example, find an element with the link 'http://google.com" in a web page. Also, there is no link text in the element:

```
<a href="http://google.com"> <span class="email-icon"> </span> </a>
```

Comment: Also, there is no link text in the element

Comment: Can u share an example of such webelements

Comment: <a href="http://google.com">
<span class="email-icon"> </span>
</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a better way than itterating over all of the `<a>` elements yourself. A simple xpath expression that looks at the `<a>` tag's `href` attribute should do the trick:

```
//a[@href='http://google.com']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it in `Ruby`. But I am sure it will be similar for PHP

```
all_links = @driver.find_elements(:xpath,"//a")
all_links.each do |link|
   print link.attribute("href") # You can use regex to check if the href includes http://google.com
end
```

The key take aways are *finding all elements* that have a tag name that starts with `a`
Then traversing through the array of found elements, and retrieving their `attribute` in this case being `href`